# Docusign: Sending a template envelope, getting “The DocumentId specified in the tab element does not refer to a document in this envelope"

Tags: docusignapi

I have a docusign request consisting of 7 documents added per individual template. For 6 of them, there's no problem. The 7th brings this error message:
 “The DocumentId specified in the tab element does not refer to a document in this envelope. Tab refers to 
 DocumentId 86106631 which is not present.”

This is really strange as the structure of the request is the same for all 7, but I delete one containing the error, it will work. I attached a masked version of the request and shortened it. Document no. 3 causes the error. 
Any ideas?

```
{
    "status": "sent",
    "emailSubject": "xxx",
    "compositeTemplates": [{
            "document": {
                "documentId": "1",
                "name": "xxx.pdf",
                "documentBase64": "xxx"
            },
            "CompositeTemplateId": "1",
            "serverTemplates": [{
                    "Sequence": "1",
                    "templateId": "e7dd1e57-81bc-49b7-9ab0-9a55ef044d00"
                }
            ],
            "inlineTemplates": [{
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "recipients": {
                        "carbonCopies": [{
                                "email": "xxx",
                                "emailNotification": {
                                    "emailBody": "xxx",
                                    "supportedLanguage": "de",
                                    "emailSubject": "xxx"
                                },
                                "routingOrder": "2",
                                "name": "xxx",
                                "recipientId": "1"
                            }
                        ],
                        "signers": [{
                                "email": "xxx",
                                "emailNotification": {
                                    "emailBody": "xxx",
                                    "supportedLanguage": "de",
                                    "emailSubject": "xxx"
                                },
                                "deliveryMethod": "Email",
                                "routingOrder": "1",
                                "roleName": "Kunden",
                                "name": "xxx",
                                "recipientId": "1"
                            }, {
                                "email": "xxx",
                                "emailNotification": {
                                    "emailBody": "xxx",
                                    "supportedLanguage": "de",
                                    "emailSubject": "xxx"
                                },
                                "deliveryMethod": "Email",
                                "routingOrder": "2",
                                "roleName": "Sender",
                                "name": "xxx",
                                "recipientId": "1"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "customFields": {
                        "textCustomFields": [{
                                "value": "XXX",
                                "name": "WorkObjectHandle",
                                "show": "false",
                                "required": "true"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "document": {
                "documentId": "2",
                "name": "xxx.pdf",
                "documentBase64": ""
            },
            "CompositeTemplateId": "2",
            "serverTemplates": [{
                    "Sequence": "2",
                    "templateId": "1a9871eb-4d48-4d1c-8144-ed17853b0e26"
                }
            ],
            "inlineTemplates": [{
                    "sequence": "2",
                    "recipients": {
                        "carbonCopies": [{
                                "email": "xxx",
                                "emailNotification": {
                                    "emailBody": "xxx",
                                    "supportedLanguage": "de",
                                    "emailSubject": "xxx"
                                },
                                "routingOrder": "2",
                                "name": "xxx",
                                "recipientId": "1"
                            }
                        ],
                        "signers": [{
                                "email": "xxx",
                                "emailNotification": {
                                    "emailBody": "xxx",
                                    "supportedLanguage": "de",
                                    "emailSubject": "xxx"
                                },
                                "deliveryMethod": "Email",
                                "routingOrder": "1",
                                "roleName": "Kunden",
                                "name": "xxx",
                                "recipientId": "1"
                            }, {
                                "email": "xxx",
                                "emailNotification": {
                                    "emailBody": "xxx",
                                    "supportedLanguage": "de",
                                    "emailSubject": "xxx"
                                },
                                "deliveryMethod": "Email",
                                "routingOrder": "2",
                                "roleName": "Sender",
                                "name": "xxx",
                                "recipientId": "1"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "customFields": {}
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "document": {
                "documentId": "3",
                "name": "xxx.pdf",
                "documentBase64": "xxx"
            },
            "CompositeTemplateId": "3",
            "serverTemplates": [{
                    "Sequence": "3",
                    "templateId": "0be0cd25-877f-4dfe-94ee-fe3cacccf9bb"
                }
            ],
            "inlineTemplates": [{
                    "sequence": "3",
                    "recipients": {
                        "carbonCopies": [{
                                "email": "xxx",
                                "emailNotification": {
                                    "emailBody": "xxx",
                                    "supportedLanguage": "de",
                                    "emailSubject": "xxx"
                                },
                                "routingOrder": "2",
                                "name": "xxx",
                                "recipientId": "1"
                            }
                        ],
                        "signers": [{
                                "email": "xxx",
                                "emailNotification": {
                                    "emailBody": "xxx",
                                    "supportedLanguage": "de",
                                    "emailSubject": "xxx"
                                },
                                "deliveryMethod": "Email",
                                "routingOrder": "1",
                                "roleName": "Kunden",
                                "name": "xxx",
                                "recipientId": "1"
                            }, {
                                "email": "xxx",
                                "emailNotification": {
                                    "emailBody": "xxx",
                                    "supportedLanguage": "de",
                                    "emailSubject": "xxx"
                                },
                                "deliveryMethod": "Email",
                                "routingOrder": "2",
                                "roleName": "Sender",
                                "name": "xxx",
                                "recipientId": "1"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "customFields": {}
                }
            ]
        }, 

    ],
    "notification": {
        "reminders": {
            "reminderDelay": "0",
            "reminderEnabled": "true",
            "reminderFrequency": "0"
        },
        "expirations": {
            "expireEnabled": "true",
            "expireWarn": "0",
            "expireAfter": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks, Regards,
Jens

Comment: I don't see any tabs in this request. Do you send them some other way? or are they part of the template?

Comment: They are part of the template.

Comment: can you check all the tabs in the template and see what is the documentID for these tabs? I supposed that you are adding a document from the API that may need to match tabs from the template and maybe there's a mismatch of the documentID

Comment: I figured out the cause. There was an additional date tag added to the document. It was so misplaced that I didn't directly see it. Removed it and it is working fine now.
Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: happy to help...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the cause. There was an additional date tag added to the document. It was so misplaced that I didn't directly see it. Removed it and it is working fine now.